# Руководство по работе с сервером версий

Tags: svn, документация, контроль-версий

Не подскажете, где посмотреть толковый сборник советов по работе с svn? Ман не нужен. Интересует: как правильно мержить, когда метки ставить и т.д. Если кто даст дельный совет  по работе c svn из жизни, будет здорово.

Answer (score 4):

http://bestblog.name/2010/01/nachalo-raboty-s-svn-checkout-update-status-ignore-log/

Comment: Для начала ок. Что дальше? :)

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion

Comment: Когда базовые понятия объясняет человек, тогда тема чувствуется гораздо тоньше и понимается гораздо быстрее, чем когда объясняет  википедия. Человеческих бы статей еще, как ссылка с bestblog.name